# Console.Logging Mapped Data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

It appears I cannot console.log any selection from an onClick for this React component. I am trying to basically achieve the following.

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ardinghelli-6seko?file=/src/demoComponent.jsx

The data is fetched from redux and appears in the frontend (I have this working).

I would like to achieve that when you select a line, it just console.logs('you have selected'role).

However it doesn't appear I can get ANY data to trigger on an onClick when it's a mapped data source.

I have implemented a p tag which fires and works as expected.

See the following refined code:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const SearchContent = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow-y: auto;
`;

const JobContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 5px 5px;
`;

export function SearchBarTrialRedux(props) {

  const inputRef = useRef();
  const [term, setTerm] = useState("")



  const handleClickRole = () => {
      console.log("Hello, you have selected" )
  }

  const searchResults = useSelector(state => state.jobsearch.roles.map(role => role.title))

  const SearchResultsText = ({ text }) => {
      return (
          <JobContainer onClick={()=> {
              console.log("Hello")
          }}>
              <JobSearchTypography 
              >
                  {text}
              </JobSearchTypography>
        </JobContainer>
      );
    };

    
  return (
          <SearchContent>
              <JobContainer >
                {searchResults && searchResults.length < 3 && searchResults.map((result) =>
                    (<IndividualContainer handleClick={handleClickRole}>
                        <SearchResultsText text={result}/>
                    </IndividualContainer>
                    )
                )}
              </JobContainer>
              <p onClick={handleClickRole}>
                fff
              </p>
         </SearchContent>
        )
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work + how to achieve the solution? I'm a little lost here!

Comment: It's not clear to me specifically what problem you're describing.  The off-site code to which you link currently has an error and doesn't run at all because it's incomplete.  Is that the error you're trying to correct?  Or, if you've already fixed that error somewhere else, what is the error you're seeing?  What data are you logging that isn't being logged?  What does this have to do with `.map()`?  Please clarify and demonstrate the specific problem.

Comment: Hi David. Sorry i have been unclear. In the demo app i copy pasted my working code which refers redux state. This obviously isn't in the demo but it's not crucial to the issue. Just assume there's 3 data titles returned. This contains 3 types of fruit. My issue is that when i map it to the frontend, which works, i am unable to console.log the selection from an onclick event. If you select say orange, i would like to console log orange. I will eventually use this variable to dispatch an update to my redux store.

Comment: Well, the code shown doesn't *attempt* to log any value.  It just logs a hard-coded string: `console.log("Hello, you have selected" )`  Did you intend to pass a value to that function?  Can you update your example with that attempt?

Comment: Hi @David, please see some updated data with the attempt. I have trailed various ways. I have included a searchResultArray with numbers, it's the same concept and same issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-ardinghelli-6seko?file=/src/demoComponent.jsx

Answer (score 1):

As it can be seen from your code snippet the `handleClickRole` function just prints to the console the message "Hello, you have selected". There is no variable passed on it in order to print it.
This can be changed like this:

```
const handleClickRole = (role) => {
  console.log(`Hello, you have selected ${role}`);
}
```

Furthermore, the way you call the above function on the onClick event I think is incomplete. It would be better if it looked like this:

```
<p onClick={() => handleClickRole(role)}>fff</p> // considering that you want to pass a variable with the role
```

or

```
<p onClick={() => handleClickRole()}>fff</p> // without a variable
```

Please also look at the below example:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [myInput, setMyInput] = useState("");
  const [isButtonClicked, setIsButtonClicked] = useState(false);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setIsButtonClicked(false);
    setMyInput(event.target.value);
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsButtonClicked(true);
    console.log(myInput);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        id=".myInput"
        placeHolder="Enter Something"
      />

      <button
        style={{
          display: "block",
          width: "100px",
          margin: "10px auto",
        }}
        onClick={() => handleClick()}
      >
        OK
      </button>

      <p style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        The entered value is:
        <span style={{ fontWeight: "400" }}>
          {isButtonClicked ? ` ${myInput}` : null}
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: *"the way you call the above function on the onClick event I think is incomplete"* - It's not incomplete in the original code, it just passes the click event and nothing else.  But in order to pass a custom argument like you demonstrate then it would indeed need to be wrapped in a function reference like you demonstrate.

Comment: Hey @David, thank you for pointing out my mistake! Yes, there is no problem with the original code as long as there is no argument. However, I think that the suggested way also helps with `event preventDefault` in recursive execution situations.

Comment: Hi @ David and @Kostas, it doesn't appear this function works. How would you map this function into the .map'd redux data? E.g in the mapped component, it is shown as text as the result. I therefore assume we use this to map the onClick? See below: const SearchResultsText = ({ text }) => {
        return (
            <JobContainer onClick={() => handleClickRole(text)}
            >
                <JobSearchTypography 
                onClick={() => handleClickRole(text)}>
                    {text}
                </JobSearchTypography>
          </JobContainer>
        );
      };

Comment: Hi all, see below. If I do a console.log of text, the data all exists and it's alligned. However it will not show for an onClick...https://gyazo.com/9b548c9f61ab515a14ed95e6a3cd2b91

Answer (score 0):

the `<IndividualContainer>...</IndividualContainer>` is a component created by you right?

if yes, then you will have to have to call the `onClick` function in the component like so:
inside the IndividualContainer component

```
  ...

   // the outer container

   <div onClick={props.handleClick}>
      ...
   </div>

  ...
```

lemme know if it works

I just edited my answer now